# How to filter out bird chirping from the background in live teams / zoom calls

Tags: sound

I have to move to our living room where we do have two budgies. If I will be in a zoom or teams call and I talk, they will start talking as well. Currently I am looking for a nice setup to filter out the sounds as good as possible. Software or hardware solution or a combination is fine for me. I know that nvidia offers a free software for any geforce users. (Nvidia RTX Voice) But currently I don't have a nvidia graphics card.

I am willing to spend a couple of dimes for that, so cost doesn't matter. (unless its over 1k euros)

Comment: What type of mic are you using? If it's a tabletop or built-in to your laptop, then moving the microphone closer to your mouth (and lowering the gain) or using a headset is the simplest way to reduce background noise. You could also look into some kind of acoustic screen.

Answer (score 2):

While the budgies won't like my suggestions, you might as it will also solve your problem.

- Buy them a cage, comfortable enough for staying in it few hours.
- When making a Zoom meeting, either cover the cage, making them think it's night and going to sleep, or move the cage to a different room where their sounds won't be heard and they won't be able to fly to the living room.

Comment: Yea they have a pretty nice cage actually with rolls, still I am about to try a different solution :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Budgie Buddies Babel Hack:**

In active noise cancellation, two microphones are used out of phase to reduce or even eliminate background noise. One microphone is used to pick-up the desirable source (you) and a secondary one is placed to pick-up everything else some distance from you—near the cage, say.

The two mics are then mixed together out-of-phase and the stronger (clean) signal is fed into the video stream.

Before you make a custom set-up, you should investigate ready-made noise cancellation microphones and headsets which have a second microphone built-in. There is specialized equipment available for video conferencing specifically.

The best set-up uses hardware (mics, mixer, and interface) and software to remove ambient background noise—both constant (hum) and intermittent (chirping budgies).

You can purchase "noise-cancellation" software and an interface for a modest budget befitting budgie-busting babel.

Good Luck.

Comment: The single mic solution sounds doable, especially if it comes with easy to use software, but getting a mixer, two mic's usable  for this, cables, etc, sounds pretty involved. Maybe if there is an inexpensive and cheap kit?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Krisp (https://krisp.ai)? It's a software solution and they offer 240 minutes of noise cancellation per week for free.

Answer (score 1):

Since your meeting can hear the birds, let the meeting see the birds. Place the cage behind you so they are visible. You can even set up a green screen on the wall so you can be in a tropical jungle.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the noise cancellation setting in Microsoft Teams? I've found it works pretty well.

[image]